# Windows leaking through bottom corners of window

Tags: windows, leak, stucco, flashing, seal

I have multiple windows leaking water into the bottom corners of window. I do not believe it is coming from above but that's just a hunch.

I had an inspection done and subsequently had all the stucco cut away and flashing redone.

Every single window still leaks just as much or more than it did and I've had over 4 different companies give me four different answers and fixes to the problem.

Window company says the stucco/waterproofing company should have fixed it. They say it's the windows.

One company wanted to change the gaskets. One to caulk the entire window to the frame. One wanted to caulk the interior of the window behind the drywall.

All of these options are thousands of dollars and I can't afford to have another misdiagnosis.

Any information would be greatly appreciated.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Looking at your pictures, no wonder it is leaking, a terrible job

Comment: I know, it looks like shit. Honestly was going to overlook that as long as the leaks stopped. Do you mind going to into a little bit of detail of why it's terrible other than looking like shit though?

Comment: The exterior looks like it desperately needs recaulking, but the window close-up. Is that double-glazed, with water inside the glazing? Really hard to tell from the picture.

Comment: Any chance it's condensation?  If it's happening on days it didn't rain, then that's it.

Comment: No, it's not condensation. I can replicate the leaks with a water hose in just a few minutes.

Comment: It's a double pane window, water is not getting in between the panes though. These seals are good. It's coming through the bottom of the frame I believe.

Comment: I still can't tell quite what I'm looking at. Is the red square the leak? https://i.stack.imgur.com/yI8hB.jpg Things to note: the blue square indicates that against all sensibility, the panes are fixed from the outside - a house-breaker's gift - & that there's no seal at all between those battens & the glass.

Comment: Water (rain) always comes from above and flows down

Comment: The one who wanted to seal on the inside should be given a good kick.  You always seal water leaks on the outside.

Comment: Any pics of the exterior bottom of the frame?